# Manifest Merger not working

Tags: android, gradle, manifest

I think the manifest merger doesnt work for me. Im running latest Android Studio 2.2.3

My Project has
:App - Application
:Library - Library Project

The Library has all activities. The app shall just use it and launch its default activity. Im just getting this error msg:

```
Error running App Default activity not found
```

This is my apps manifest:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="trainer.de.next"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

</manifest>
```

The merged manifest shows not more, this is the report:

```
Manifest Sources 
app main manifest (this file)
 Other Manifest Files (Included in merge, but did not contribute any elements) multidex:1.0.1 manifest
```

In the build.gradle of app im using the library

```
...
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}
```

Comment: This is going to sound silly... but are you sure that your library has a manifest?

Comment: yes; are there any settings which may prevent merging? created a new library from scratch, this is recognized

Comment: "are there any settings which may prevent merging?" -- none that I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: I was having a productFlavors section in my library builds.gradle; removing it and it works